# PHP - Array mapping or filtering

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter, array-map

Sorry for the vague title, I had trouble summarizing this question in one sentence (I'm open to suggestions or edits).

I have a 2 dimensional associative array with an array of 2 numbers for each key.

Like this:

```
Array
   (
   [one] => Array
      (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 2
   )
   [two] => Array
      (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 2
   )
   [three] => Array
      (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 2
   )
)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to use array_map() or array_filter() to return an array that has each key and the first number in each of the value arrays, like this:

```
Array
   (
   [one] => 1
   [two] => 1
   [three] => 1
)
```

I do not wish to create a new array by using a loop or anything like that, I'd like to do the conversion on the fly as an argument to a function, if you know what I mean.

I could write my own function to achieve this but I'm interested in knowing if it can be done with array_map() or array_filter().

I tried using various combinations of array_merge(), array_keys() and array_values() with no success.

I thank you in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Oh wow, I totally forgot to say I'm using PHP. Sorry about that!

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should know that `array_walk` has lower performance then `foreach` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to use loop instead in this condition. However this one should work with your case.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
   "one" => array(1, 2),
   "two" => array(1, 2),
   "three" => array(1, 2)
);
$res = array();

array_walk($arr, function ($v, $k) use (&$res) {
    $res[$k] = $v[0];
});

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first [solution](https://3v4l.org/ImkUV) is:

```
$keys = array_keys($ar);             // get all keys
$vals = array_column($ar,0);         // get all values with 0 index
$res = array_combine($keys,$vals);   // combine them
```

By the way, you don't need to use some extra function, simple `foreach` loop would be [enough](https://3v4l.org/JlXJk):

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $res[$key] = $val[0];
}
```

You can see the difference between performances of `array_walk` and `foreach` function [here](http://www.ktorides.com/2015/02/php-array_walk-vs-foreach/).

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of array_column(), will definitely be using it in future. Although this is not quite what I was looking for.. I am trying to see if it is possible to do it in just 1 function call instead of 3.

Comment: @vulpinus, yes, it's possible. That's why I've wrote *the first solution*.

Answer (score 2):

with array_map you can do somthing like that :

```
$array_2= array_map(function ($sub_array) {
 $new_value  =   $sub_array[0];
 return $new_value;
},$array_1);
```

Comment: Explain what are `$array_2`, `$array_1` and `$sub_array`.

Comment: `$array_1` is the input data, `$array_2` is the output data that we want. and `$sub_array` in fact they are sub arrays inside first array. take a look at my answer i use the same approach but with a callback function and more details. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_reduce` to iteratively reduce the array.

```
return array_reduce(array_keys($attribs), function($carry, $key) use ($attribs){
        $carry[$key]= $attribs[$key][0];
        return $carry;
    });
```

Hope this help,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done using only one function `array_map` with a callback:

1. map will iterate over arrays inside `$arr`
2. callback take only first element of array as you want.

```php
<?php
$arr = array(
   "one" => [1, 2],
   "two" => [1, 2],
   "three" => [1, 2]
);
$res = array_map(fn($sub_arr)=>$sub_arr[0],$arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
/*
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 1
    [three] => 1
)
*/
```